# Solr boost score based on wikipedia PageRank and solr score

Tags: solr, wikipedia, pagerank

I have solr indexed wikipedia dump. I get the results from solr query which have results shown according to the lucene score.

In the indexed files from Wikipedia i also have the field: PageRank calculated based on the inbound links to the title.

I want to get more relevant results based on the lucene score and the PageRank field.

What should be my approach here?.
How can i boost the results based on both the values.

Appreciate any leads.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the standard query parser or extended dismax, you can use this query

```
q=[your query]+AND+_val_:"PageRank"
```

Using both regular document score AND custom score based on the value of a field is the default behavior when you use the SolR FunctionQuery with the _val_ hook. 
See here: 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Using_FunctionQuery

> If you use a function query as 'just another term' (for example, by
>   using the special field name *val*), the value of the function becomes
>   a component of the overall query score, just as with any other part of
>   the query. This includes the standard normalization, which amounts (by
>   default) to multiplying scores by a magic constant (by default, that
>   is inverse of the square root of the sum of squared weights).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know.